# return a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, return

i want to check if a number is even by use of **function** and return in **Javascript**. here goes my code. It should return true when number is even otherwise it should return false.

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if(number%2 === 0) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
};
```

the code doesn't work. Instead it works when the quotation marks ( "...") around true and false are removed. Why? I mean the words true and false are strings, hence should be included inside quotation marks.
please help,

Comment: `true` and `false` are booleans, not strings.

Comment: The simplest way is just `function isEven (num) { return num % 2 === 0 }`.

Answer (score 4):

it should works:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return !Boolean(number % 2);
};
```

in additional how to create `isOdd`:

```
var isOdd = function(number) {
    return !isEven(number);
};
```

**Reason why you can't return "true" for boolean:**

Everything that exists between marks "..." in javascript's recognized as type `string`. This also applies to empty string `""`, some examples:

```
typeof("") => "string"
typeof("true") => "string"
typeof(true) => "boolean"
```

Comparison with others languages you have to pay attention for size of characters, fe:

```
typeof(TRUE) => "undefined" (because it could be name of variable)
```

In additional:
be consider to use `==` and `===`. Example:

```
"" == 0 => it's a true
"" === 0 => it's a false
```

Some examples for build-in `Boolean` function:

```
Boolean("") => false
Boolean("1") => true
Boolean("0") => true
```

Comment: The use of `Boolean` is not necessary here. Just use `return !(number % 2);`.

Answer (score 4):

If you put `true` and `false` in quotation marks, it will return a string value, because `"true"` is a string, whereas `true` is not. If you want to return a boolean, just return `true` or `false`.

```
if(number % 2 === 0) return true;
else return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing like this

```js
var isEven = n => !(n%2);
console.log(isEven(1));
console.log(isEven(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if` at all. Just return the result of the comparison

```
var isEven = function(number) {
   return number%2 === 0;
};
```